# External Content Type Search not returning results

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, crawl-external-content

I have configured my 2010 External Content Type for search by adding the `RootFinder` property to the `ReadList` method. I have also added the `ShowInSearchUI` property to the LOB entry. I then set up my content crawler in Enterprise Search Service Application and kicked off a full crawl. The log shows 2002 items (which makes sense since the `ReadList` query in the service sets a limit of 2000 rows) and no errors on the crawl.

The problem is when I go to perform a search, the site comes back with **no results found**. Searching for criteria in other lists and libraries works so I know the search service as a whole is working. I just cannot seem to find any results from the ECT source.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bcs/archive/2010/01/05/todd-baginski-s-how-to-series.aspx) by Todd Baginski, especially `HOW TO: Register an External Content Type with the SharePoint Search Service to make the data searchable` part, it may be helpful.

Comment: I am still working through this so once I get the search working I plan on marking this as the answer. My initial attempt after reading the posts failed.